# proftpd rewrite rule to replace backslash to slash

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, proftpd

I try to use the following rule but it doesn't work. Proftpd v1.3.4a. 
Has someone any idea, what is wrong?
The rule have to change backslash to slash when changing or creating directories

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteLog /path/to/proftpd/rewrite.log

    # Use the replaceall internal RewriteMap
    RewriteMap replace int:replaceall

    RewriteRule (.*) "${replace:!$1!\\\\!/}"'
</IfModule>
```

Comment: There's a typo in the [Rewrite howto](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Rewrite.html).  It _should_ be `RewriteRule (.*) "${replace:!$1!\\\\!/}"` (no trailing single quote).

Comment: Thank you, but my config file is without single quote

Comment: Does your config have a `RewriteCondition`, _e.g._ `RewriteCondition %m "^(CWD|MKD|XCWD)$" [NC]`, to tell `mod_rewrite` _when_ it should apply the `RewriteRule`?

Comment: Yes, my config have

Comment: Yes, my config have RewriteCondition %m
For linux command line following rule is ok only if command is at " "
If I tested by Total Commander command line was ok without " " too.  RewriteRule ^(.*) "${replace:!$1!\\!\/}"

Comment: Next week will be tests and I've hope, that all will be ok